# Android: Error with adding textview to linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, scrollview

Here is my app's OnCreate method:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection_screen);

        // this is automatically added by eclipse
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        log("Was here!");
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrolllayout);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appsRunning = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();

        log("Now here!");
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo v : appsRunning) {
            TextView TVinfo = new TextView(this);
            TVinfo.setText(v.processName);
            log("Looping here!");
            layout.addView(TVinfo, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            log("Looping here!");
        }

        appsRunning = null;   
        log("Finally here!");
        ScrollView scrollRunningApps = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        scrollRunningApps.invalidate();
        scrollRunningApps.requestLayout();
    }
```

Whenever, the app starts the above method is executed, it always crashes right after adding the first view to the linear layout object. So this is the log output:

```
06-10 01:13:23.172: I/TIMER(8319): Was here!
06-10 01:13:23.172: I/TIMER(8319): Now here!
06-10 01:13:23.172: I/TIMER(8319): Looping here!
```

This is my xml file, I left out the parts that are irrelevant:

```xml
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/welcome_textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/welcome_textView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrolllayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: post your logcat then.

Comment: is the layout you posted activity_selection_screen.xml?

Comment: @blackbelt, No it is from fragment_selection_screen.xml

Comment: then your application is crashing for NPE. Do you really need more information?

Comment: @blackbelt, yes please if you have an idea

Comment: When you set height and width of first textview to `MATCH_PARENT` then where it should add the second textview? I guess this is the problem. Try changing them to `WRAP_CONTENT`

Comment: @Aniruddha, thanks for the suggestion, but it is still crashing

Comment: you are looking for `scrolllayout` that is declared in `fragment_selection_screen.xml`, **but** setContentView took `activity_selection_screen.xml` as paramter

Comment: @blackbelt, Ok I changed it to now load `fragment_selection_screen.xml`, but it is now crashing after running OnCreate. OnCreate is the only method I have implemented. The other methods handle the options menu of the app which have nothing in them atm. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: don't take it personally, but *witch-hunts* ended around the 18th century. When your application crashes you should post **always** the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** First create a file `ids.xml` in your `/res` directory and add the following XML schema to this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type = "id" name = "mytextbox"></item>
</resources>
```

**2.** Your `onCreate()` method should look like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection_screen);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

**3.** Add the following code to your `PlaceholderFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.scrolllayout);
    EditText e = new EditText(view.getContext());
    e.setId(R.id.mytextbox);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    e.setLayoutParams(lp);
    l.addView(e);

}
```

Try this. It will work.

**NOTE:** I can see that you attempted to add the `EditText` from your `Activity`, and maybe you don't want to do it from your `Fragment`. If you would still prefer to do it from your `Activity`, let me know. There are ways to do it, but when dealing with a `Fragment` it is always safer to add/remove views after the `Fragment` has been successfully created.

Comment: You're the best, thank you so much! Ok, just incase I wanted to do everything from the activity class, how would I do that?

Comment: You are most welcome :) By the way, I made a small edit to the `onCreate()` method in my answer. Please make sure you write it that way. If you still face any problems, let me know.